# Spring+JPA+MVC (No Maven) Error creating bean

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, jpa

First of all, I am really sorry for asking this question, because I saw a same problem with me here ([Spring + JPA + MVC - Error creating bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9167637/spring-jpa-mvc-error-creating-bean)) but I still do not know how to fix things in my situation. Because:

- I am very new to Spring and I am doing a project in a very short time.
- The imported project uses Spring 2.5.6 (very old). All jars file stay in 'lib' folder and it doesnt use Maven.

When I imported the project, it displayed those bugs. What I learnt from "[Spring + JPA + MVC - Error creating bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9167637/spring-jpa-mvc-error-creating-bean)" is that I need to resolve conflict between jars files. **But I still have no clues what jars file I need to change even I spent whole day for this minor task.**

This is the picture of my 'lib' items: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAg5v.png

I really appreciate any helps.

```
11-11@23:30:36 ERROR (ContextLoader.java:215)     - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name     'org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0' defined in class path resource [ssel/banking/dao/jpa/banking.dao.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [ssel/banking/dao/jpa/banking.dao.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: BankingWeb] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:480)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:880)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:596)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:365)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:675)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:601)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean    with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [ssel/banking/dao/jpa/banking.dao.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: BankingWeb] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:308)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:270)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.detectPersistenceExceptionTranslators(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:122)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:78)
at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.java:70)
at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.setBeanFactory(PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.java:97)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1326)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
... 38 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: BankingWeb] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:677)
at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:132)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:224)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1369)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1335)
... 55 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Duplicate property mapping of name found in ssel.banking.domain.Account
at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkPropertyDuplication(PersistentClass.java:477)
at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:467)
at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:215)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1135)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1320)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:867)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:669)
... 60 more
```

Comment: What makes you think you have conflicting versions of librares? The error is caused by "Duplicate property mapping of name found in ssel.banking.domain.Account". Why don't you check the mapping of this property?

Comment: Check domain class 'ssel.banking.domain.Account' seems like you have duplicate mapping. Check all annotations(@Column, @JoinColumn, ...) whether do you see any duplicate mapping names ?. Or may be because of inheritance/embedded you might end up in duplicate mapping indirectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the stack trace that doesn't look like a conflicting JAR issue it looks like there's a problem with

```
ssel.banking.domain.Account
```

Check there's not more than one field mapping to the 'name' column. Worth checking parent classes/sub classes as well for properties with the name 'name'.

Posting the contents of ssel.banking.domain.Account may help if the above isn't true.

The core of the problem is:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Duplicate property mapping of name found in ssel.banking.domain.Account
```

Comment: Yes.. that's the answer.

Comment: thank you alex.p. You saved my day. How bad I was when I did not notice that. 
I got this exception because of a duplicated 'name' fields in the supper class. 
My solution is to put @Transient at that field in the supper.